# iPhone5 IOS 7.1.2 Bluetooth Connect Unknown error

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

When connect with bluetooth pripheral device, I got the follow error number.
CoreBluetooth[WARNING] Unknown error: 1309

Has anyone explain this?

Comment: Have see the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623013/ios-bluetooth-ble-writevalue-return-unknown-error) , it says its ios device DB management problem. But I want to know how to make it work while appear? or some avoid advice ?

Comment: I have searched apple doc, and found that it can be to see the iOS Bluetooth logs. After install an profile, and have found Diagnostic Mode on iOS device Bluetooth Setting. Refer apple link [link](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/bluetooth/). Than, sync log files to my computer. And found ATT & XPC ....